# Is violence especially discouraged during Ramadan? And what about lesser jihad?

Tags: ramadan, jihad, violence

Is violence especially discouraged during Ramadan?

I've heard people talk about Ramadan as a month that's meant to be peaceful, but I'm worried that they may be Christians who think that if Christmas is supposed to be peaceful, then the same must be true about Ramadan.

I tried looking at the "religious practices" and "crime" sections of Wikipedia's [Ramadan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan) article, but couldn't find anything.

Also, are individuals deciding to engage in, or exhorting others to engage in, lesser jihad specifically during Ramadan a modern phenomenon, or did it happen in historical times?

Comment: There are 4 months in which Muslims are asked to be "peaceful" unless they need to defend themselves: the ashhor al horum: three successive Dhi-l Qi'adah, Dhi-l Hijjah and Moharram (the 11th, 12th and 1st Month of a Hijri Year) and one single Month Rajab (7th Month). See for example http://legacy.quran.com/2/217, http://legacy.quran.com/2/194 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 types of the lesser, Fard Kifaya (offensive, not obligatory. such as expanding into new land) should not take place. while Fard Ayn (defensive and obligatory(not sure if to all or just to those who are males and "able")) should take place. an example of this would be the Syrian army fighting off daesh during Ramadan.

ramadan as well as the other 3 peaceful months should not host non-necessary conflict. a state should not be expanding but fighting for control of borders or attacking in order to free slaves or captives is ok.

*this is only my view/outlook, please don't rely on me (much of my information is from our far-right and from a book I read from a very harsh person, Abdullah azzam)*

Answer (score 1):

There are four sacred months in which initiating<sup>1</sup> warfare is \ was<sup>2</sup> forbidden. They are listed in the hadith:

> السنة اثنا عشر شهرا منها، أربعة حرم، ثلاث متواليات، ذو القعدة وذو الحجة والمحرم ورجب
>
> The year is twelve months, four of which are sacred. Three of them are in succession; Dhul-Qa'da, Dhul-Hijja and Al-Muharram, and the fourth is Rajab
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4662)</sup>

Ramadan is **not** one of the four sacred months. Hence Jihad is permitted during Ramadan. During the time of the Prophet ﷺ the [Battle of Badr](https://sunnah.com/ahmad:142) and the [Conquest Makkah](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4275) occurred in Ramadan - which proves that fighting Jihad in Ramadan is permitted.

---

1 <sub>Defending is permitted even during the sacred months, by consensus.</sub>

2  <sub>According to the majority of the madhabs, the prohibition of fighting in the sacred months is abrogated in our shariah. See https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/227931/</sub>